# Photo-Captions are missing when posting a Photo on Tumblr

Tags: caption

So everytime I post a photo I write a Caption, but on my Tumblr-Site no one can see it

What Code do I need to have visible Captions?

Answer (score 2):

The page [How to create a custom HTML theme](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts) explains it all: you probably have not included such caption constructs in your theme code. Note that at Tumblr Audio, Video and Photo posts, "caption" can be a full sized HTML text, not only a "title", as the term "caption" often refers to ..